# Ошибка запроса ajax

Tags: javascript

Выдает ошибку в консоли `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.`

Сам запрос

```
$("#id_button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var UserId = $('input[name=SteamId]').val().trim();
    if (!UserId) {
        alert("Вы забыли указать имя");
        return;
    }
    console.log("id_button");
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "...users/add/?usersid=" + UserId,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.steamid);
            $("#steam-id-result").text(data.steamid);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Вы делаете запрос на другой домен?

Comment: @entithat Я думаю, автор просто отрезал кусок домена. Или не знает что нужно писать в `url`

Comment: да, мой проект лежит на codeanywhere.com

Comment: А доступ к коду, с которого должен прийти ответ - есть?

Comment: в url лежит ссылка на добавление в бд

Comment: Есть доступ, в network вкладке отображаються данные

Comment: Проверьте мой ответ. Обращаю ваше внимание, что вам нужно поправить не тот код, который отправляет запрос. А тот, который возвращает вам ответ

Comment: я добавил header что предложили с ниже и все заработало, спасибо

Comment: Если ответ вам подошел - отметьте его как верный, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если есть доступ к коду сервера, на который вы делаете запрос - добавьте в заголовок ответа следующую строку:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

В случае с `php` это будет что-то вроде такого:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Вместо знака `*` вы можете вписать свой домен, с которого делаете запрос.
Если вы не можете править код сервера - у вас не получится отправить запрос к домену, который возвращает ответ без этого заголовка.